# Azue AD - How to re-enable user, assign password, convert shared mailbox to regular mailbox

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps, azure-ad-graph-api

We have a requirement to automate re enabling the rehired users in azure active directory. Upon rehirig the employee into the company, we need to enable his/her account and assign  a password to let the user logon to the company portal. Also we need to convert his mailbox which was converted to shared when he last left from the company to a regular mail box. All this i want to acheive through logic app and graph api. I don't see much help on the web regarding this. Can somebody help with this?

Thanks,
Venu

Answer (score 0):

> You can see all the users that were deleted less than 30 days ago.
> These users can be restored.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-restore#view-your-restorable-users

Your requirement is cannot archive. One user, neither create new, neither restore after 30 days, neither deleted permanently (need re-create new).